# Icons Only Appearing When Hover

Tags: ruby-on-rails, icons

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now and can't seem to get it to work.

I'm trying to use icons within my rails app, both bootstrap and Font Awesome icons, and when I use them in conjunction with a link it makes the text of the link hide and the text and icon only appear on hover. What could be causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the font color and background the same?  If so the hover is set to change colors and that would explain it.

Comment: No they're not the same. The text/link shows up fine in the navbar, I inject an icon, refresh, no text or icon but when I hover it I can see it. Weird.

Comment: gonna need to see some code then

Comment: yes it's better to print a snippet of your code

Comment: It's just weird, and its global, so I don't know what code to really show you. I installed the font awesome gem, and called it properly, its actually working. But when i add a logo to my site, refresh, it doesnt show. Then, when i click my logo to go to root path it reloads the page and shows. I have no clue why. Somethings loading wrong within my rails app I think.