# HOW To have icon appear in a row when my mouse hovers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am using feather icons, and i would want the feather trash to appear beside the item name when my mouse hovers it.

I see this persons asking the question on Stacks but no answer was found.

[Icons Only Appearing When Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210918/icons-only-appearing-when-hover)

My code below:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class=" text-center">Item#</th>
          <th class=" text-center">Item Name</th>
          <th class=" text-center">Qty</th>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1,001</td>
          <td>Apple</td>
          <td class=" text-right">5</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1,002</td>
          <td>Kidney Beans</td>
          <td class=" text-right">3</td>

        </tr>
```

[image: What i want]

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749276/css-on-hover-show-another-element/43588892

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The principle:

```
tr .fa {                            /* row not hovered */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-out; /* adding transition, improved UI */
  cursor: pointer;                  /* change cursor when hovering icon */
  transition-delay: .5s;            /* delay the icon fading out */
}

tr:hover .fa {                      /* row hovered */
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0s;             /* cancel delay when entering */
}
```

In its simplest form:

```
tr .fa {
  opacity: 0;
}
tr:hover .fa {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Working example:

```css
tr .fa {
  margin-right: .5rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-delay: .5s;
}
tr:hover .fa {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class=" text-center">Item#</th>
          <th class=" text-center">Item Name</th>
          <th class=" text-center">Qty</th>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1,001</td>
          <td><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Apple</td>
          <td class=" text-right">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1,002</td>
          <td><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Kidney Beans</td>
          <td class=" text-right">3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Feel free to change the selectors so that you don't affect anything else and that they match your current markup.
In your case, you'll want want to replace `.fa` selector with `[data-feather]`.

Comment: tao.. this definitely work in your example.. that is exactly what i want.. can you advise if the principle should be post in my css file? or in my html sheet using script open and close?

Comment: @S, remember to upvote any helpful answer and to mark one as accepted. This improves indexing and, overall, helps future users find the right answers faster.

Comment: definitely.. thanks again, tao - does stack offers one and one sessions? like if i want to pick your brain directly, every now and then?

Comment: Not really, but I just made [this public room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213476/andrei-gheorghiu). I'll get notified when I get mentioned in it. Most likely, I'll still want you to ask a proper question, so that anyone with the same type of problem might benefit from an answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a class to your icon element
2. Hide it by add this attribute `style="display: none;"`
3. Add the hover effect to your CSS file: `.youriconclass:hover {display: block;}`

Comment: tried this with the current code i have, and it shows up as blank.. in addition, i am link my css via html link, how do i edit the bootstrap.min.css file? i think someone advise not to edit this, if i got it local?

Comment: Don't edit your bootstrap.css file. If you want to add custom CSS then create your own style.css file and link to it in the <head>

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery hover method** can help you accomplish the task. First, you need to add some HTML modifications like create a container for the icon. e.g.

```
      <td class="trigger-icon">
         Apple 
         <span class="icon-container"> </span>
      </td>
```

Now for the js part,

```
    $(".trigger-icon").hover(function(){
     $(".icon-container").append('<i data-feather="trash"></i>');
    }, function(){
     $(".icon-container").empty();
    });
```

For feather icon to work,

```
   $(".trigger-icon").hover(function(){
     $(".icon-container").append('<i data-feather="trash"></i>');
     feather.replace();
    }, function(){
     $(".icon-container").empty();
    });
```

Comment: quick question.. the js part, can i have that at the bottom of my html
between <script type="text/javascript">   JS PART < /script> or i have to do something different?

Comment: It should be inside the $(document).ready method. For reference, see this https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_hover

Comment: Nafiz its not working for me.. been trying both examples//

Comment: Will it be possible to share the js code in codepen so that I can look into the structure? Can you check whether you can do with simple text like '<div>Hello</div>' instead of  '<i data-feather="trash"></i>'?

Comment: Yes.. how do i do that?

Comment: you can use https://codepen.io/ or https://github.com/ or you can update the question with js code block. Anything that will be easy for you.

Comment: how can we take this in chat to discuss?? The version you sent in w3schhols.com works perfect.. But when i try to get the icon appear when hover, doesnt work..

Comment: I get it work. Please check  https://codepen.io/redoy11/pen/qBOoypr